# how to remove second element in queue?

Tags: java

I am a beginner with data structures and I'm trying to remove and return a specific element from a queue.

My idea was to remove all the elements in a queue until I reach the element and then just add back that specific element that I need.

However I'm not sure how to add back that element after removing all the elements. Can someone please explain how you can achieve this?

```
public static Object removesecond(Queue queue){
   Queue q = new Queue(queue.size());


   queue.remove(); // remove

   queue.remove();
   Object removed = queue.remove();
   // remove first 2 elements and store it in object



    queue = q;

    System.out.println(""+removed); 


     return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to change your structure to List, the principle of queue is to remove only the head element

Comment: What's `Queue`? It certainly is not the one from the standard library (since it's an interface). What methods does it have? Anyway, if you need that kind of behavior you're looking for something that is not actually a queue, since a queue doesn't have that behavior. Have you thought of using something like a simple array? Either that, or you move everything but the element you want removed to another queue.

Comment: @leobogod Did you try to compile this code?  Where is the Queue class defined?

Comment: Is it the second element or any element ? please update the question title or content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (but in reality is a bad practice).

```java
      Queue<Integer> ad = new ArrayDeque<>();
      ad.add(10);
      ad.add(20);
      ad.add(30);
      Iterator<Integer> a = ad.iterator();
      a.next();
      a.next();
      a.remove();
      System.out.println(ad);
```

However, a queue is a FIFO data structure and is meant to remove elements in the order they were added.  You may want to use a different collection like a `List` implementation.

Comment: Beware that `Queue` seems to be a custom object, which may not be `Iterable`.

Comment: True.  I assumed it was the JDK version.

Comment: They are instantiating it, so it can't be (`Queue` is an interface)

Comment: Then any solution provided can't be certain it will work since we don't know the names of the methods or capabilities.  Nor does anyone know if the OP actually tried to compile the provided code. And I doubt it was done since it has one too many right braces.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that kind of behavior you're looking for something that is not actually a queue, since a queue doesn't have that behavior.

Have you thought of using something like a `List`?

Anyway, since your `Queue` seems to be a custom class I'll suppose you could have a `size` method to know how many objects it contains (I see that in your example) and a `push` method to put an element in the queue. In this case, we can remove all elements and put them back as we go along, skipping the second one (and keeping it aside to return it at the end)

```
public static Object removesecond(Queue queue){
    Object toReturn;
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
        Object o = queue.remove();
        if (i != 1) queue.push(o)
        else toReturn = o;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Of course this is a naive implementation. You may want to check if you have at least two elements first, check if `queue` is not `null` and define what should happen otherwise.

**EDIT**

In your comment you asked how you can return (so I'll assume also remove) the second element from the end in case you're using an `ArrayDequeue`. Of course you can do it the same way as above (using `add` instead of the method I called `push`).

If you want to do it directly you can convert the list to an array (with the `toArray(T[])` method), convert the array to a `List`, remove the unwanted element and keep it aside, clear your queue, put the elements of the `List` back in the `Queue`, return the removed element.

Which is very wasteful and takes a lot more time than the other method, but here it is anyway.

```
public static Integer removesecond(ArrayDequeue<Integer> queue){
    Integer toReturn;
    Integer[] arr = queue.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
    toReturn = list.remove(list.size() - 2);
    queue.clear();
    queue.addAll(list);
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , is there a way to return that specific element or you cannot do that with a queue?

Comment: As I pointed out, what you're using is **not** the `Queue` interface we all know and love, it's something else, so it depends on what `Queue` *actually* is. And only you can tell us that.

Comment: how would you do it using the Queue interface class ?`Queue<Integer> ad = new ArrayDeque<>();`